# Is it possible to use pure CSS to set <img> height according to its 100% width if the widht/height ratio is fixed?

Tags: html, css, image

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <p>blah blah ... </p>
  <img style="width:100%" src="..." />
  <p>blah blah ... </p>
</div>
```

The image would “flash” before its rendering - because its height is `0` if you don't declare it in the CSS. This is very annoying for my users.

However, I tried something like this:

```
img {height:calc(width/2)}
```

or this:

```
img {height:50%}
```

It's not working.

I have many pages like this and all the images are in a **2:1 width/height ratio**.

Is there anything I can do in Pure CSS to make the image element as big as of the rendered size, so that before its loading, it won't break the page's layout.

By “Pure CSS” I mean, there should not be extra JavaScript or HTML. For instance, the `img` is the child of `div#wrap` and I want it remains this way.

Update:

I found another answer suggest me to use `calc(100vw * .5)`. However, this doesn't solve my question. `100vw` is a fixed width - the width of the viewport. What I want is something like `calc(100 * this(width) * .5)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid Cumulative Layout Shift while the image is loading you would need to use a wrapper. I know this is not what you asked for but as far as I am aware there is no other way than to alter the HTML.

The trick is to create a 0 height wrapper with padding the same height as your aspect ratio.

So in the example below I have 3 images with an aspect ratio of 16:9 (or 2:3). As such I create container with the correct padding height using `calc(100% * 2/3)`.

This will then be covered by the image once it loads.

The `.container` is purely to let you see all the images load in.

It does rely on your knowing the image aspect ratio before it loads.

```css
.container{
    width: 15%;
}

.image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}
.image {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/3000x2000.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/4500x3000.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/3750x2500.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### Chrome and Firefox

Chrome and Firefox has both introduced native aspect ratio space saving (I do not know the proper name for it as you can probably tell!)

If you give you image a width and height the browser will allocate space for it, even if the image itself is a different size than specified.

**please note** - you must give the image a width and height of 100% for this to work.

Notice how in the following example the widths and heights I have set are aspect ratio relevant but do not affect the container size. Obviously set these widths and heights to something more sensible in production.

```css
.container{
    width: 15%;
}
.image{
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/3000x2000.jpg" width="6" height = "4"/>
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/4500x3000.jpg" width="3" height = "2"/>
      <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/3750x2500.jpg" width="3750" height = "2500"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both attributes, width and height, like:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Although it will usually work if you only have either `width` or `height`, your situation is probably a bit different in that you are using percentages to deal with the image width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class or id to the image and set it to `width:100%` and `height:100%`. Keep in mind that it will always be a 100% of the parent div in this case. Here's a [very simple fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/8vs3haqk/)